# Android LocationManager shows non-existing gps provider always enabled

Tags: android, locationmanager

I need to use get user location data using any available provider. When all providers are disabled I need to popup a dialog and enable user to go to Location services and
enable a provider (GPS and/or network whichever is available). I ran into a problem of checking if provider is available on Prestigio PMP5197D ULTRA. It does not have GPS service.
I've used the following code:

```
// I get and log list of disabled providers...
ArrayList<String> names = (ArrayList<String>)locationManager.getProviders(false);
for(String t: names){
    Log.e("TEST", "DISABLED " + t);
}

// I get and log list of enabled providers...
ArrayList<String> names2 = (ArrayList<String>)locationManager.getProviders(true);
for(String t: names2){
    Log.e("TEST", "ENABLED " + t);
}
```

On following devices everything is ok...

**NEXUS 7 (2013) (4.3)**

LOCATIONS DISABLED IN SETTINGS

DISABLED passive

DISABLED gps

DISABLED network

ENABLED passive

LOCATIONS ENABLED IN SETTINGS

DISABLED passive

DISABLED gps

DISABLED network

ENABLED passive

ENABLED gps

ENABLED network

**HTC Desire (2.2.2)**

LOCATIONS DISABLED IN SETTINGS

DISABLED network

DISABLED passive

DISABLED gps

ENABLED passive

LOCATIONS ENABLED IN SETTINGS

DISABLED passive

DISABLED gps

ENABLED network

ENABLED passive

ENABLED gps

but on this tablet I get GPS as always active, which is very strange as I do not have GPS on the device. And of course, there is not an option for GPS in settings.

**Prestigio PMP5197D ULTRA (4.0.3) - the device does not have GPS**

LOCATIONS DISABLED IN SETTINGS

DISABLED network

DISABLED passive

DISABLED gps

ENABLED passive

ENABLED gps

LOCATIONS ENABLED IN SETTINGS

DISABLED network

DISABLED passive

DISABLED gps

ENABLED network

ENABLED passive

ENABLED gps

When user tries to click location button, in case location services are disabled (only network available) I should popup beforementioned dialog for the user. 
But, as the location manager's method isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) returns true, it looks like GPS is enabled, live and kicking. So, I do not
show dialog to the user, and also none of the data are fetched.
Does anyone know about any workaround for this problem?